# Staying logged in as a user for remote access (such as Team Viewer) Pros & Cons

Tags: authentication, user-management, teamviewer

This company we newly help have no remote access policy for say, but they allow the users to use Team Viewer.  I have noticed some user leave their PC logged in all night and weekends and just shut the screen to save time at login.  So they can open Team Viewer, login and voila there in.

*Keeping in mind that:

1. We have re-vamped their password by giving the maximum Team Viewer password strength possible/allowed by Team Viewer (length, characters, etc.)
2. The office is physically secured, so let's not worry about someone sneaking in and such.

What would be the true Cons?  The pros are mainly for end user to save time...

Answer (score 1):

There still are two risks even with good password strength and good access control in the office.

- Even if Team Viewer pays high attention to security, there is still a possibility of the program being compromised, as in remotely exploitable by some kind of vulnerability. PC's staying on in the week-end would allow an attacker to freely use the exploit while the guy supposed to monitor security is doing a BBQ with his friends.
- The access control might be as good as you want, but if the threat comes from inside it is useless. Let's say the manager is on a business trip and lets his pc on to access with TeamViewer from his laptop, John who is a bad guy, wants access to said manager's info for whatever reason, he can stay in office until 7:30pm and wait until everyone has gone home and have fun with the manager's data.

Except for this, AFAIK it should pose no problem. It is a matter of how much you trust Team Viewer and how much the company trusts its employees.